# Write Dynamic Connection String to XML file

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

I want my dynamic SQL connection string to be saved to XML file. Below is my code to save connection String to SQLSettings.Dat file.

I want that, It should be saved to XML file as well, like App.config file.

```
Public Sub dbConnection()
    If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\SQLSettings.dat") Then
        Dim quoteArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\SQLSettings.dat")
        For Each Item As String In quoteArray
            connstring = $"Data Source={quoteArray(0)};Initial Catalog={quoteArray(1)};User ID={quoteArray(2)};pwd={quoteArray(3)};"
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("Database settings not exists, save settings before!")
        frmDBSettings.ShowDialog()
        Application.Restart()
    End If
    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following xml linq

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Public Sub dbConnection()
        Dim xmlHeader As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><ConnectionStrings></ConnectionStrings>"

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader)
        Dim connectionStrings As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim connstring As String

        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\SQLSettings.dat") Then
            Dim quoteArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\SQLSettings.dat")
            For Each Item As String In quoteArray
                'Console.WriteLine(Item)
                connstring = $"Data Source={quoteArray(0)};Initial Catalog={quoteArray(1)};User ID={quoteArray(2)};pwd={quoteArray(3)};"
                Dim connectionString As New XElement("ConnectionString", connstring)
                connectionStrings.Add(connectionString)
            Next
            doc.Save(FILENAME)
        Else
            MsgBox("Database settings not exists, save settings before!")
            frmDBSettings.ShowDialog()
            Application.Restart()
        End If

        Try
            conn = New SqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = connstring
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: it worked fine, thanks just changed a bi, moved these line outside of loop

Dim connectionString As New XElement("ConnectionString", connstring)
                connectionStrings.Add(connectionString)

Comment: You need it inside the For loop otherwise you only get one results (the last one).